# GParted- how to increase size of partition near start of drive?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

My drive looks something similar to this (from start to end of drive):

```
/dev/sda1        100 MB           ntfs System Reserved
/dev/sda2        21.48 GiB:       extended
   /dev/sda5     13.68 GiB        ext 4
   /dev/sda6     7.8 GiB          linux swap
/dev/sda3        146.49 GiB       ntfs
unallocated      55.50 GiB        unallocated
```

I want to increase the size of my linux partition (i'm not sure if I need to increase the whole "extended" or just "ext 4"?) to use up all of the unallocated disc.

Could someone please walk me through what I need to do?

I thought it would let me just specify the extended to increase in size and then shift the Windows 7 partition accordingly, but its not letting me and warned about not being able to boot the Windows 7 partition.

Comment: Moving sda3 to the left of sda2 is in general a bad idea unless you have no choice. Win7 will definitely not boot after that, but you can fix that. More importantly, it will take a _very_ long time even on a fast machine and creates a big risk of data loss to both sda2 and sda3. You are better off creating a new (primary) partition out of the unallocated space and installing Ubuntu there.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not letting you resize that partition because you are currently booted into it.  Try booting from a live disk (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) with gparted (you may have to install gparted within the livedisk instance, depending on the flavor of linux or Ubuntu you have burned) and resizing the partition from there.

Also, i just remembered, you could just burn a gParted Live Disk, if you didn't want to wait to boot into an entire Ubuntu instance (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have unallocated `55GB` of space under the `dev/sda3` partition.Follow the below steps to increase the size of your linux partition.

1.Download [`Gparted-live.iso`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) file and make it bootable through usb or burn the iso to dvd or cd.

 To increase the size of a linux partition,make sure that it must be unmounted.So that we use gparted cd.

2.Rightclick on the `dev/sda2` extented partition and  select **Resize/Move** option.Increase the size of dev/sda2 partition by how much of space you want to allocate for linux partition.

3.Then unallocated space comes under /dev/sda2 partition.

4.Right click on the `linux ext4` partition then selct *move/resize* option and add the desired space.